# Where do I need to load chunks of user's data and what is the best way of doing it?

Tags: node.js, express

For example, I have a social network. There are many of users. They all have many comments on their walls, videos, friends etc. A user goes on another userpage and then my client make a call to server to load some data, about this user. A userpage has: avatar, comments on user's wall,  friendlist and some small pieces of data, such as status etc.

```
...
try {
      const user = await User.findById({ _id: userId })
        .populate('friends')
        .populate('wallcomments.user')
        .populate('requests')
        .populate('newmessages.user')
        .populate('messages.receiver')
        ...
```

I don't think this is the best way, because a user doesn't even need all comments or all of user's friends. 10 would be enough.

So I think, I need initially load and `populate` 10 of users, comments etc. and then when user needs more he clicks on the button and the client makes a call to the server to load and `populate` 10 more of comments or friends...

What is the best way of doing it and how actually do that on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually quite a difficult question and there is no magic-bullet solution for it.

However there is one technology that is doing exactly what you need - load only the things you ask for:
https://graphql.org/

Try the learn-section, there are live examples.

(btw: It was introduced by Facebook and is used by Facebook)